# Android communication with microcontroller via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, microcontroller

I'm developing an application which communicates with a microcontroller via bluetooth. I'm sending a packet made up of byte array which is successfully being received. However, the byte array sent by the microcontroller is not being received by me. There is no error coming up. The receiving code is below:

```
private void beginListenForData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("clientsocket", "listening data");
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final byte delimiter = 10; // This is the ASCII code for a newline
                                // character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();

                    if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                        Log.e("bytes", "" + bytesAvailable);

                        Log.e("bytes", "" + bytesAvailable);
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        Log.v("packet Bytes", "" + packetBytes);
                        for (int m = 0; m < packetBytes.length; m++)
                            Log.e("checking array", "" + packetBytes[m]);
                        Log.v("packet bytes len", "" + packetBytes.length);
                        mmInputStream.readFully(packetBytes, 0,
                                packetBytes.length);

                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if (b == delimiter) {
                                byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0,
                                        encodedBytes, 0,
                                        encodedBytes.length);
                                for (int k = 0; k < encodedBytes.length; k++)
                                    Log.v("encoded bytes", ""
                                            + encodedBytes[k]);

                                int[] iarray = new int[encodedBytes.length - 1];
                                int k = 0;
                                for (int j = 0; j < encodedBytes.length - 1; j++)
                                    iarray[k++] = encodedBytes[j] & 0xff;
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                                        iarray.length);
                                for (int l : iarray)
                                    sb.append(l);
                                for (k = 0; k < iarray.length; k++)
                                    Log.v("iarray", "" + iarray[k]);

                                final String data = sb.toString();
                                // final String data = new String(
                                // encodedBytes, "UTF-8");

                                Log.e("data server", data);

                                readBufferPosition = 0;
                                Log.e("clientserver", "" + data);
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                        myLabel.append("\n" + data);

                                        System.gc();
                                        Log.e("clientserver", "" + data);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {

                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    stopWorker = true;
                    myLabel.append("\n" + "Try Again!");

                }
            }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();

}
```

Initially, when the microcontroller was sending data in a String, it was being read by me successfully. But when it switched on to byte array, the problem started. Can somebody please help me with this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Can u post ur logcat ?

Comment: What's your transmit code?

Comment: Solved the problem!
It was because the delimiters were not matching at both ends. thanks for your concern. :)

Comment: Please either answer your own question using the "Your answer" below, or remove it...  Answering your own questions is just fine (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and a community, we prefer not to have unanswered questions floating around.  In this case there is probably no value to future site users as this question is rather specific (and the problem doesn't appear to be in the code you posted), so it probably makes the most sense to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem! It was because the delimiters were not matching at both ends. thanks for your concern. :)